# Auto hide taskbar entirely?

Tags: windows, taskbar

I'm using the auto hide feature in W8.1, but even using it still leaves a thin amount of the taskbar, presumably to allow you to see pinned icons and such, which really bugs me, is there any way to hide it completely?

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called ShyBar that does this: http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/321184-shybar-automatic-windows-7-taskbar-hider.html